# Spring batch - Processor or Writer?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

In my Spring boot and Spring batch application, I have a step like this:

```
    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<FileInfo, FileInfo>chunk(10).reader(FileInfoItemReader).processor(processor()).writer(writer()).build();
    }
```

My writer is a empty like below:

```
public class BlankWriter<T> implements ItemWriter<T> {

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends T> items) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

Now, in my processor I have this:

```
  public class FileInfoItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<FileInfo, FileInfo> {

   .....

    @Override
    public FileInfo process(final FileInfo FileInfo) throws Exception {

     myCustomStuff () {
       ......
     }
    }
    
    public static void myCustomStuff() {
       ......
       ......
    }


  }
```

**Question:** As all the objects are passed to processor, I can deal with them in my processor itself rather using any transformations etc AND since my purpose get solved by using processor, is it a good practice? or I must use a writer/custom-writer to get the job done?

Comment: What does your item processor do for your items? If you can elaborate on `myCustomStuff`, I can try to help you identify what could be done in the processor and what could go in the writer.

Comment: @Mahmoud, I am making REST POST calls in my processor’s myCustomStuff.

Comment: @Mahmoud, any suggestion for me?

Comment: Yes, I added an answer with more details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think doing the REST POST call in the writer is more appropriate than doing it in the processor. A REST POST call is a kind of write operation to a remote location.

So you can omit the processor (since it is optional) and move that code to the item writer (instead of using a NoOp item writer with an empty `write` method).

Comment: Yes, you are right. Making REST API call in processor is fine, when need to enrich the request object or validate some business logic. But to store the data in external system, it's better to make REST call in the writer instead of processor.

Comment: Great. If the answer helped, please consider accepting it. Thank you.

Comment: I think, it asked by @ajaykumar and he can only accept.

Comment: Thanks Paramesh for the comment. I liked it. @MahmoudBenHassine, thanks for finding time and writing the answer. Accepting it.