# Could it be a good idea to put the business logic calling external APIs into a Spring Batch writer? (to persist information into another system)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am pretty new in Spring Batch and I have the following doubt about **ItemWriter** and how to correctly implement this behavior.

At the moment I have this class configuring a job:

```
@Configuration
public class UpdateNotaryDistrictsJobConfig {
    
    private static final String PROPERTY_REST_API_URL = "rest.api.url";
    
    @Autowired
    private NotaryListServiceAdapter notaryListServiceAdapter;
    
    @Autowired
    private NotaryDistrictsListServiceAdapter notaryDistrictsListServiceAdapter;
    
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;
    
    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;
    
    @Autowired
    private NotaryService notaryService;
        
    @Bean()
    public ItemReaderAdapter serviceNotaryDistricItemReader() {
        ItemReaderAdapter reader = new ItemReaderAdapter();
        reader.setTargetObject(notaryDistrictsListServiceAdapter);
        reader.setTargetMethod("nextNotaryDistrictElement");

        return reader;      
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Step readNotaryDistrictsListStep(){
        return steps.get("readNotaryListStep").
                <Integer,Integer>chunk(1)  
                .reader(serviceNotaryDistricItemReader())
                .processor(new NotaryDistrictDetailsEnrichProcessor(notaryService))
                .writer(new ConsoleItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean(name="updateNotaryDistrictsJob")
    public Job updateNotaryDistrictsJob(){
        return jobs.get("updateNotaryDistrictsJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(readNotaryDistrictsListStep())
                .build();
    }
    
}
```

It works fine. Basically this job is composed by a single step itself composed by:

1. A **READER**: read data from an external API.
2. A **PROCESSOR**: enrich current element calling another API and obtaining details.
3. A **WRITER**: simply write the data into the console.

It works fine but now I have to totally change the behavior of my writer that have not to simply write the data into the console.

At the moment my writer is something like this:

```
public class ConsoleItemWriter extends AbstractItemStreamItemWriter {
    
    static int elementNumber = 0;
    
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    
    @Override
    public void write(List items) throws Exception {
        //items.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
        
        items.stream().forEach(item -> {
                                            //NotaryDistrictDetails notaryDistrictDetails = (NotaryDistrictDetails) item;
                                            System.out.println("WRITING OUTPUT: " + item.toString());
                                            
                                            String jsonObj;
                                            try {
                                                jsonObj = objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(item);
                                                System.out.println(jsonObj);
                                            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                            
                                        });
        
        System.out.println(" ************ writing each chunck ***********");
    }
}
```

As you can see it simply print each object in the console.

Now my writer must persist an object into a WordPress website calling several APIs. Basically I have implemented several service methods that implement the logic to operation needed to persist these data as WordPress post into a wordpress website.

Basically my idea was to use these method and implement the business logic into this writer. Bascailly instead to only print the data the writer will also implement business logic like this:

1. Check that the current object exist or not as post into the WordPress website
2. If the object doesn't exist as post into the WordPress site, simply insert this object.
3. If the object already exist as post into the WordPress site, delete the old version and insert it again.

All the methods calling the WordPress API in order to check if an object exist as post  into the WordPress website and to delete and insert these information as post into WP website was implemented into a service class.

Could be a decent idea put the previous business logic (that calls these service methods) into a my Spring Batch writer?

Comment: I have ItemWriters that call web services to update external systems, so this is definitely a valid use case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring batch - Processor or Writer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068906/spring-batch-processor-or-writer)

Comment: I think this is a valid use case as well, see my answer in the duplicate question.